# Actionscript 3 - make movieclips fluid resize according to the menu (movieclip) shifting

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, fluid-layout

I have learned Fluid Layout from tutsplus.com

but how to make a movieclip change size according to the menu (movieclip) shifting as in 
[flashnifties](http://flashnifties.com/products/flash-media-gallery/) -- http://flashnifties.com/products/flash-media-gallery/

Answer (score 0):

You should use any [DisplayObjectContainer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html) in order to control the view of your movieclip (we usually use [Sprite](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html)). I tried the app from your link and it seems that movieclips don't change their scale - they just slide to the side when you minimize the menu

So you will have the following:

1. Your Sprite that contains your movieclip, e.g.

   ```
   mcContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
   ```

   Which you will add to your display list somewhere.
2. An Event.ENTER_FRAME event listener to create smooth animation (tween libraries will also do)
3. When you hit the minimize menu button you move the container of your movieclip (mcContainer) to the left for a few pixels in every frame, as well as the container of your menu:

   ```
   yourEnterFrameEventListener(e:Event){
       mcContainer.x -= 3;
       menuContainer.x -= 3;
   }
   ```

   In this case your menu and your movieclip will move for 3 pixels in each frame.
   If you don't want to depend on your framerate, just calculate the passed time and multiply it by your speed

The width of the text fields can be done the same way - you edit the .width properties of your textfield to make it wider.

Comment: thank @Kumo Kairo, but if you look again at the example in the link, the menu is only slide, but was followed the widening of the main contents according the menu sliding

Comment: You can "tween" the movieclip size the same way you do it with your coordinates.
Just add 
mcContainer.width += 3;
mcContainer.height +=3;
after you change the coordinates.

Or download something like TweenLite and tween these properties